# Displaying whole menu item upon getting a focus in scrollable menu using CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

[Here is my example](http://jsfiddle.net/5rS5Q/1/).

A focused menu item must show up wholly, not partially. I know it can be aligned with the menu container via JavaScript's `onfocus` handler but wonder if there is a purely CSS solution.

EDIT: For now, to move on, I had to resort to [JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/5rS5Q/3/), but the question is deliberately left unanswered as it is about CSS.

Comment: Maybe you need to explain your problem a bit more. All i can see it 2 and a half links. What exactly do you want

Comment: @MarsOne: When the half item gets focused, I need it to scroll left/right so that it gets fully visible.

Comment: I think you should consider using javascript for this. Using Css would be too complicated

Comment: _“All i can see it 2 and a half links”_ – ah, a new nerd-spinoff of a famous comedy series …

Comment: @MarsOne: Overall I don't mind using even too complicated CSS solution, at least I like a declarative way of defining UI, while a programmatic one is mostly to define business logic. Thanks to AngularJS, the required behavior can be applied via an HTML attribute or style.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to give the items a width or min-width of half of the container. That should trigger all browsers to handle it automatically.

I am not even sure it is possible any other way(with pure css) without being able to select a previous sibling or parent element.

Comment: The width of menu items is variable (not fixed), sometimes they may be wider than the container.